# Fastest way to find rows without NaNs in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I would like to find the indexes of rows without any NaN in the fastest way possible since I need to do it thousands of times. So far I have tried the following two approaches:

```
find(~isnan(sum(data, 2)));
find(all(~isnan(data), 2));
```

Is there a clever way to speed this up or is this the best possible? The dimension of the data matrix is usually thousands by hundreds.

Comment: Can you tell what would you like to do with the indices of ~NaN...  may be it is not necessary to find again, isnan returns 0 and 1. You can use them (0 & 1) cleverly--

Comment: In my application these indices will interact with other indices, so it is much more natural to operate on indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** 
matrix multiplication can be faster than sum, so the operation is almost twice faster for matrices above 500 x500 elements (in my Matlab 2012a machine).  So my solution is:

```
find(~isnan(data*zeros(size(data,2),1)))
```

---

Out of the two methods you suggested (denoted `f` and `g`) in the question the first is faster (using [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798)):

```
data=rand(4000);
nani=randi(numel(data),1,500);
data(nani)=NaN;
f= @() find(~isnan(sum(data, 2)));
g= @() find(all(~isnan(data), 2));
h= @() find(~isnan(data*zeros(size(data,2),1)));

timeit(f) 
ans =
     0.0263

timeit(g)
ans =
     0.1489

timeit(h)
ans =
     0.0146
```

Comment: I got similar numbers to these comparing the first two methods but you beat me to it :-) +1

Comment: Yes I do find the first method being faster than the second one. Also it seems like the `sum` is costing more overhead than the `find`, because removing the `find` only speeds up a little bit from what I can see.

Comment: col = size(data,2)  ......
sum(data,2) <=> data*ones(col,1)  ...
Try multiplication instead of sum for large size, it may save millisec

Comment: See my edit, I think I've found a faster way using matrix multiplication with a zeros vector...

Comment: The matrix multiplication method is not faster on my machine. If you run the code say 1000 times and look at the average, the method using `sum` is still the fastest.

Comment: what size of matrix are you using? for lower matrix size there is little difference between the two, so sometimes sum looks faster and sometime matrix multiplication looks faster...

Comment: The matrix I tested on was thousands by hundreds. In practice the size can vary by one order of magnitude on each dimension, so maybe there isn't one method thats always better.

Answer (score 2):

If the `nan` density is high enough, then a double loop will be the fastest method. This is because the search of a row can be discarded as soon as the first `nan` is found. For example, consider the following speed test:

```
%# Preallocate some parameters
T = 5000; %# Number of rows
N = 500; %# Number of columns
X = randi(5, T, N); %# Sample data matrix
M = 100; %# Number of simulation iterations
X(X == 1) = nan; %# Randomly set some elements of X to nan

%# Your first method
tic
for m = 1:M
    Soln1 = find(~isnan(sum(X, 2)));
end
toc

%# Your second method
tic
for m = 1:M
    Soln2 = find(all(~isnan(X), 2));
end
toc

%# A double loop
tic
for m = 1:M
    Soln3 = ones(T, 1);
    for t = 1:T
        for n = 1:N
            if isnan(X(t, n))
                Soln3(t) = 0;
                break
            end
        end
    end
    Soln3 = find(Soln3);
end
toc
```

The results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.164880 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.218950 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.068168 seconds. %# The double loop method
```

Of course, the `nan` density is so high in this simulation that none of the rows are `nan` free. But you never said anything about the `nan` density of your matrix, so I figured I'd post this answer for general consumption and contemplation :-)

Comment: very nice, the double loop is faster in matlab, who would have thought? +1

Comment: The density of NaN is about 5%~10%.

Comment: @ezbentley Ah well, if that density is randomly and evenly distributed across all elements, then this is probably too low for the double loop to be faster in native Matlab. However, if you implemented a double loop in C or Fortran and compiled it as a mex, this would almost certainly be faster...

Comment: I think I got to the double loop speed without using a double loop, see my edit...

Comment: @natan Very nice. I got good numbers for it on my machine too... afraid I can't +1 you a second time though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more about what you want to do with the indices

```
time = cputime;  
    A = rand(1000,100);              % Some matrix data
    for i = 1:100  
        A(randi(20,1,100)) = NaN;    % Randomly assigned NaN  
        B = isnan(A);                % B has 0 and 1  
        C = A(B == 0);               % C has all ~NaN elements
        ind(i,:) = find(B == 1);     % ind has all NaN indices
    end
    disp(cputime-time)
```

for 100 times in a loop, 0.1404 sec

Answer (score 0):

`any()` is faster than `all()` or `sum()`.
try:

```
idx = find(~any(isnan(data), 2));
```

correction: it seems that `sum()` approach is faster:

```
idx = find(~isnan(sum(data, 2)));
```

Comment: I see different results when benchmarking with your solution, it is faster a bit than `all`, but much slower than`sum`.